# How to have a fail-over resilient SQL Server view over linked mirrored database table

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, mirroring

Say I have a set of servers with mirrored application databases and a set of statistics servers where a couple of the tables are exposed from the application database as views (with some tenant specific filtering). The view looks something like

```
... as select * from [server].[table] where tenant_id = xyz
```

Is there a way to create the view such that it doesn't depend on which of the applications server is primary. The view stops working after every fail-over and someone has to fail-back the DB.

What is the best practice when it comes to situations like this? Any not-so-best solution?

Comment: What version and edition of SQL Server? Have you considered using AlwaysOn where you can use a listener name that doesn't change after failover?

Comment: 2008 R2. Availability groups therefore not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I haven't tested but how about openrowset? Native client is deprecated so there might be a bit of work needed to get it running, depending on what SQL server version youre're running, but then again so is mirroring I suppose. How about something like this:

sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;

GO

sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO

Create view MyView

AS

SELECT a.*
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=Server1;FailoverPartner=Server2;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
                 AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Department) AS a;

GO

Comment: In my testing, so far, I have noticed SQL server can no longer use statistics with OpenRowset and the end effect is horribly slow queries.